# Showing product specs using HTML helper

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have this piece of code to show a table of product specs.

```
<h4>Product Specs</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

@foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SpecItemsModel> spec in Model.Specs)
{

    string label = Model.Specs[spec.Value.LatinName].Name;
    int id = Model.Specs[spec.Value.LatinName].Id;
    string name = Model.Specs[spec.Value.LatinName].LatinName + "_" + id;


    object val = Model.Specs[spec.Value.LatinName].SpecValue != null ? Model.Specs[spec.Value.LatinName].SpecValue : string.Empty;

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("", label, new { @class = "contorl-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">


        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As a result, a table is shown with spec titles but no spec value. What I want to know is what html helper should I use to show spec values.

Comment: I'm assuming `string label` is the value you're referring to?

Comment: also, can you provide the model you're using on this?